# Doxygen for a multi-language API

Tags: c++, matlab, vb6, doxygen, python-sphinx

My company develops a API for engineering programs. It is developed in C++ but we create wrappers to it for the following languages:

- a proprietary language that resembles VB
- MATLAB
- and Python.

Currently the documentation is generated by a bunch of scripts and it is starting to get time consuming to keep it 100%. I was wondering if there is a way to get doxygen/sphinx or another program to generate the documentation for C/C++, VB and MATLAB in one go. The Python part is done by SWIG. Currently the output is something like:

- NameOfFunction
- VB:
- Function NameOfFunction(ByVal a As Long , ByRef b() As Long, ByVal c As Long) As Long
- MATLAB:
- value = NameOfFunction(a,b(),c)
- C/C++:
- value *NameOfFunction(objtype1 *a, objecttype2 *b[], int c)
- +Description
- +Examples

Comment: isn't there a config script you can edit for doxygen?

Comment: Yeah, but how can I accomplish what I want. I had a look at it, but could not find something that looked like what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

doxygen supports multiple languages,

to use this on multiple projects or folders and languages you just point doxygen to every folder you want checked in the config.

My favorite programming language is X. Can I still use doxygen?

No, not as such; doxygen needs to understand the structure of what it reads. If you don't mind spending some time on it, there are several options:

Is language X supported?

> If the grammar of X is close to C or C++, then it is probably not too
>   hard to tweak src/scanner.l a bit so the language is supported. This
>   is done for all other languages directly supported by doxygen (i.e.
>   Java, IDL, C#, PHP). If the grammar of X is somewhat different than
>   you can write an input filter that translates X into something similar
>   enough to C/C++ for doxygen to understand (this approach is taken for
>   VB, Object Pascal, and Javascript, see
>   http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#helpers). If the
>   grammar is completely different one could write a parser for X and
>   write a backend that produces a similar syntax tree as is done by
>   src/scanner.l (and also by src/tagreader.cpp while reading tag files).

however since your using a VB like proprietary , it might pick this language up if you simply just change the file extensions to that of .vb

here is how to use it with [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25925-using-doxygen-with-matlab)

python and c++ are already supported

have a look at the F[AQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#12) page

Answer (score 2):

The Doxygen site has a page with links to 3rd-party helpers for various languages, that you may be able to adapt:

http://www.doxygen.nl/helpers.html

VB and MatLab filters are mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if there is a way to get doxygen/sphinx or another program to generate the documentation for c/c++, VB and matlab on one go.

The Zeus editor has a [doxygen feature](http://www.zeusedit.com/zoxygen.html) that allows you to create doxygen documentation for all items in the Zeus workspace.

Comment: Thanks, but I find it difficult to get all the developers to start using other IDE.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that just using a particular editor will magically make doxygen support arbitrary files.

Comment: In response to Ben Voigt: There is no magic. The feature I described is nothing more than any file added to a Zeus workspace will be sent to doxygen for processing. How well doxygen handles that file is up to doxygen, but Zeus will make sure it is processed. That's it, nothing more nothing less.